# After Click on SaveTask Button, Task in not adding in Main Activity display. and App is crashing. Please check layout manager is properly set or not

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview

We have looked at a number of posts and tried a few with no results.
Here is the [Github link](https://github.com/pankaj104/One-Task-Add) for full code.

Here is the code for the activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/todoRv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/AddTask"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="25dp"
        android:onClick="openNewTask"
              />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code for the activity_task.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activity.TaskActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTaskName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Task Name"
        android:layout_margin="14dp"
        android:textSize="33sp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etTaskName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Please Enter Task Name"
        android:layout_margin="14dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveTask"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="saveTask"

        android:text="Save Task" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code for the item_todo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtShowTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:text="Task Title Name" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code for the MainActivity.kt

```
package abc.com.onetaskadd.activity

import abc.com.onetaskadd.R
import abc.com.onetaskadd.adapter.TodoAdapter
import abc.com.onetaskadd.database.TodoDatabase
import abc.com.onetaskadd.model.TodoModel
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Adapter
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val todoList = arrayListOf<TodoModel>()
    var recyclerAdapter= TodoAdapter(todoList)
    lateinit var layoutmanger: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
    lateinit var todoRv:  RecyclerView
    val db by lazy {
       TodoDatabase.getDatabase(this)
   }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        todoRv= findViewById(R.id.todoRv)
        todoRv.apply {
            layoutmanger= LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            adapter=this@MainActivity.recyclerAdapter

        }


        db.todoDao().getAllTask().observe(this, Observer {
            if (!it.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                todoList.clear()
                todoList.addAll(it)
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        })
    }
    fun openNewTask(view: View) {
        startActivity(Intent(this, TaskActivity::class.java))
    }


}
```

Here is the code for the TaskActivity.kt

```
package abc.com.onetaskadd.activity

import abc.com.onetaskadd.R
import abc.com.onetaskadd.database.TodoDatabase
import abc.com.onetaskadd.model.TodoModel
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.SyncStateContract.Helpers.insert
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
const val DB_NAME = "todo.db"


class TaskActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var etTaskName: EditText
    lateinit var saveTask: Button

    val db by lazy {
        TodoDatabase.getDatabase(this)
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_task)
        etTaskName = findViewById(R.id.etTaskName)
        saveTask= findViewById(R.id.saveTask)

    }


    fun saveTask(view: View) {
        val taskName = etTaskName.editableText.toString()
              GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val id = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                return@withContext db.todoDao ().insertTask(
                        TodoModel(
                                taskName
                        )
                )
            }
            finish()
        }


    }





}
```

Here is the code for the TodoAdapter.kt

```
package abc.com.onetaskadd.adapter

import abc.com.onetaskadd.R
import abc.com.onetaskadd.model.TodoModel
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class TodoAdapter (val todoList: List<TodoModel>) :RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.TodoViewHolder>(){

    class TodoViewHolder(view: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
    {
        fun bind(todoModel: TodoModel) {
        with(itemView){

            val txtShowTitle: TextView= findViewById(R.id.txtShowTitle)
            txtShowTitle.text=todoModel.taskName
        }
        }

           }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViewHolder {
        val view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_todo, parent, false)

        return TodoViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
       holder.bind(todoList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return todoList.size
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the TodoDao.kt

```
package abc.com.onetaskadd.database

import abc.com.onetaskadd.model.TodoModel
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.Query

@Dao
interface TodoDao {


    @Insert()
  suspend  fun insertTask(todoModel: TodoModel):Long

    @Query("Select * From TodoModel where isFinished != -1 ")
    fun getAllTask():LiveData<List<TodoModel>>
}
```

Here is the code for the TaskDatabase.kt

```
package abc.com.onetaskadd.database

import abc.com.onetaskadd.activity.DB_NAME
import abc.com.onetaskadd.model.TodoModel
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(entities = [TodoModel::class],version = 1)
abstract class TodoDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun todoDao(): TodoDao

    companion object{
        @Volatile
        private  var  INSTANCE: TodoDatabase? =null
        fun getDatabase(context: Context): TodoDatabase {
            val tempInsance = INSTANCE
            if (tempInsance != null) {
                return tempInsance
            }
            synchronized(this){
                val instance= Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        TodoDatabase:: class.java,
                        DB_NAME
                ).build()
                INSTANCE= instance
                return  instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the TodoModel.kt

```
package abc.com.onetaskadd.model

import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey


@Entity
data class TodoModel(
val taskName: String,
var isFinished: Int =-1,
@PrimaryKey
var id:Long=0

)
```

Comment: Can you add the Logcat output or the error message you got it,

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace this code in TaskDatabase.kt file

```
        synchronized(this){
            val instance= Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    TodoDatabase:: class.java,
                    DB_NAME
            ).fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()
```

It will Solve the debug problem.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.